# bash menu list script syntax error

Tags: bash, shell

I dont understand what went wrong to my script.... I am having a syntax error. Initially it was working without the while switch. I added the while switch and it stopped working and now even when im removing it it doesnt work lulz.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ARGS=1
 E_BADARGS=85

 if [ $# -ne "$ARGS" ]
 then
 echo "Usage: `basename $0` <pcap file>"
 exit $E_BADARGS
 fi


{ NUMBER_OF_WHATEVER="$(cmd1)";} 2>/dev/null 

{ NUMBER_OF_WHATEVER2="$(cmd2 | wc | awk {'print $1'})";} 2>/dev/null

{ NUMBER_OF_TCP1="$(cmd3 | wc | awk {'print $1'})";} 2>/dev/null

{ NUMBER_OF_UDP2="$(cmd4| wc | awk {'print $1'})";} 2>/dev/null



HTTP_PERC="$(python -c "print float( ('"${NUMBER_OF_HTTP//\'/\\\'}"'))*100 /     float(('"${NUMBER_OF_TCP//\'/\\\'}"'))   ")"

UDP_PERC="$(python -c "print float( ('"${NUMBER_OF_UDPFLOWS//\'/\\\'}"'))*100 / float(('"${NUMBER_OF_TCP//\'/\\\'}"'))   ")"




echo "$(tput setaf 6) Select Option: "
echo "$(tput setaf 6)1) Analysis1"
echo "2) Analysis2"
echo "3) Test3"
echo "4) Test4 "
echo "5) Test5 "

while true; do
    read -p "Choose Option: " n

    case $n in
    1)  echo "Analysis1"

        echo ""

        echo ""

        echo "=============================================================="
        echo "Pcap File details: "



        echo "=============================================================="


        #echo "Press 1 to return or anything else to exit: ${CHOICE}"

        ;;

    2) echo "Starting Analysis2"

               echo "EOF";; 
    3) echo "Test3"

           printf "\n"

           echo "End of TCP flows";;
    4)  echo "Test4"
        echo "";;

    *)  echo invalid option
    ;;

   esac
 done
```

Comment: I ran your code, there doesn't seem to be any syntax errors at all.

Comment: actually what im getting is 'unexpected end of file'

Comment: I ran your code too and I didn't get any syntax error. is the script executable? could you please tell us which is the error ? did you wrote the script on windows and then trasfert it on unix? maybe wrong transfer (binary) could affect the script

Comment: I think that something broken from the transfer of notepad++ (windows) to linux... pfffff Thanks and sorry for the post